# CGI в Python на Mac

Tags: python, mac, cgi

Хотел использовать cgi в проекте на python. Возникает такая проблема на Mac. Этот же проект работает на Windows.Но после переноса на Mac возникает такая ошибка при обращении к файлу в папке cgi-bin[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Права на исполнение в Mac и Linux задаются атрибутом файла. Выполните

```
chmod a+x cgi-bin/hello.py
```

Также в первую строчку файла добавьте интерпретатор для него

```
#!/bin/env python
```

Comment: А можно права на исполнение задавать без терминала ? Ну или как быть если нужно запускать этот сервер в браузере. То есть этот hello.py должен в браузер результата выдавать.

Comment: Можно правой кнопкой мышки и в свойствах файла поставить

Comment: В свойствах поставил Чтение и запись для файла, но эт не помогло, мб что-то не так понял ?

Comment: Выполнение, выполнения файла не хватает

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду ?